# Error in generating a chart: No images in the collection intersect the specified regions

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, ndvi, time-series, chart

I am getting an error saying:

> no images in the collection intersect the specified regions

thus my time-series chart cannot be generated.

What might be the reason for this?

The link to my code
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fmpalasimbarashe%2FProject1%3AkNDVI_Sample2

```
////// DEFINING THE GRASS LOCATION ////

var Grass = Grass.map(function(feature) { 
  return ee.Feature(feature.geometry(), {'id' : feature.id()})
   })
   
Map.addLayer(Grass,{color:'green'},'Vegetation')

///// FUNCTION TO MASK THE CLOUDS ////
function maskCloudAndShadows(image) {
  var cloudProb = image.select('MSK_CLDPRB');
  var snowProb = image.select('MSK_SNWPRB');
  var cloud = cloudProb.lt(5);
  var snow = snowProb.lt(5);
  var scl = image.select('SCL');
  var shadow = scl.eq(3); /// 3 = cloud shadow
  var cirrus = scl.eq(10); /// 10 = cirrus
  // Cloud probability less than 5% or cloud shadow classification
  var mask = (cloud.and(snow)).and(cirrus.neq(1)).and(shadow.neq(1));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

/// SELECTING THE DATE RANGE ////

var startDate =  new Date ('2020-10-01')
var endDate =  new Date ('2020-10-30')
var startDateMillis = startDate.getTime(); // FOR DATE VISUALIZATION
var endDateMillis = endDate.getTime(); // FOR DATE VISUALIZATION


//// COMPUTING THE KNDVI BAND/////
var addKNDVI = function(image){
  
  var RED = image.select('B4');
  var NIR = image.select('B8');
  
/// COMPUTE D2 A RENAME TO d2 ///
 var D2 = NIR.subtract(RED).pow(2)
 .select([0],['d2']);
 
 /// GAMMA DEFINED AS 1/sigma^2
var gamma = ee.Number(4e6).multiply(-2.0);

/// COMPUTE KERNEL (k) AND KNDVI ///

var k = D2.divide(gamma).exp();
var kndvi = ee.Image.constant(1)
    .subtract(k).divide(ee.Image.constant(1).add(k))
    .select([0],['kndvi']);//.clip(Grass);

  // MAKE A DATE BAND IN UNIX TIME (MILLISECONDS FROM UNIX EPOCH)
  var dateBand = ee.Image(image.date().millis()).toLong().rename('millis');    

/// CALCULATE THE MEAN KNDVI WITHIN THE GEOMETRY ///
var kndviMean = kndvi.reduceRegion({ 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
  geometry: Grass,
  scale: 10,
  bestEffort: true,
  maxPixels: 1e10
  });

/// ADD KNDVI &  DATE BANDS, SET KNDVI GEOMETRY MEAN AS A PROPERTY
return image.addBands(ee.Image([kndvi,dateBand])).set(kndviMean);
 
};

//// IMPORTING THE IMAGE COLLECTION ////

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                   .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                   .map(maskCloudAndShadows)
                   .map(addKNDVI)
                   .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(Grass))
                   
/// VIEWING THE MEDIAN COMPOSITE ////
 var vizParams = { bands: ['B4','B3','B2'] , min: 0, max: 2000}
 Map.addLayer(collection.median(),vizParams, 'collection')


/// Getting Time Series for a singe Location ///

var testPoint = ee.Feature(Grass.first())
//Map.centerObject(testPoint, 10)
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
    imageCollection: collection.select('kndvi'),
    region: testPoint.geometry()
    }).setOptions({
      interpolateNulls: true,
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
      title: 'KNDVI over Time at a Single Location',
      vAxis: {title: 'KNDVI'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Date', format: 'YYYY-MMM', gridlines: {count: 12}}
    })
print(chart)


////// Exporting time series for a single location ////

var filteredCollection = collection.select('kndvi')
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(testPoint.geometry()))
var timeSeries = ee.FeatureCollection(filteredCollection.map(function(image) {
  var stats = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: testPoint.geometry(),
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e10
  })
  // reduceRegion doesn't return any output if the image doesn't intersect
  // with the point or if the image is masked out due to cloud
  // If there was no ndvi value found, we set the ndvi to a NoData value -9999
  var kndvi = ee.List([stats.get('kndvi'), -9999])
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull())
 
  // Create a feature with null geometry and NDVI value and date as properties
  var f = ee.Feature(null, {'kndvi': kndvi,
    'date': ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd')})
  return f
}))
 
// Checking the results
print(timeSeries.first())
 

// Export to CSV
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: timeSeries,
    description: 'Single_Location_kNDVI_time_series',
    folder: 'earthengine',
    fileNamePrefix: 'kndvi_time_series_single',
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
})

// //// GETTING TIME SERIES FOR MULTIPLE LOCATONS /////

// var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
//     imageCollection: collection.select('kndvi'),
//     regions: Grass,
//     reducer: ee.Reducer.max()
// })
// // This doesn't work as the result is to large to print
// print(chart)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the point you are using for your chart `var testPoint = ee.Feature(Grass.first())` is not a valid geometry. If you print `Grass`, and look at the first feature, you'll see it has no coordinates listed.

[image]